# Make CLI with argparse and setuptools

Tags: python, argparse, setuptools

I have a module sfind.py. How can I do this so that I can run the script by the file name without the py prefix?

```
 python sfind instead python sfind.py
```

**sfind.py**

```
import argparse


def createParser():
    some logic
    return parser

def main(namespace):
    some logic


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = createParser()
    namespace = parser.parse_args()
    main(namespace)
```

I tried to do it with setuptools, maked new file setup.py in same directory.

**setup.py**

from setuptools import setup

```
setup(
    name='sfind',
    version='0.1',
    packages=['sfind'],
    entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'sfind=sfind:__main__'
    ]
})
```

But error occurred

```
python: can't open file 'sfind': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can anybody help me do it right?

**File structure:**

```
-sfind
  --__init__.py
  --__main__.py
  --sfind.py
  --test.py
```

Comment: Did you run `python setup.py develop` or `python setup.py install`? You won't use the command `python` with this, it would just be `sfind <args>`.

Comment: Also, this won't execute `sfind.py` as `__main__`. It will execute the `main()` function, as that is what you have specified the entrypoint as.

Comment: @jordanm  If I run `python setup.py install` i have same error. And I replaced main to __main__

Answer (score 2):

You don't need setuptools to call your module as `python sfind`. Setuptools will allow you to call by just `sfind`. To call it with `python sfind`, you have to make your `sfind` a module and you can do this by making a python directory `sfind` with `__init__.py`, `__main__.py`, and `sfind.py` in the directory. Then, you can call with just `python sfind`. If you just want to call it with `sfind`, you can use setup tools, but it is recommended you provide callable function (e.g. `sfind=sfind.sfind:main`) instead of module itself (`__main__`) as your `entry_points`. You can then do either `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py sdist` then `pip install`.

Comment: thank you for such a detailed response. Then I do not understand why the script does not run after the call `python sfind`. I have ` __init__`file in my folder. 
Is it enough that the program is considered a module?

Comment: @lepiloff sorry i forgot to mention you need include `__main__.py` in your package which should include your `argparse`

Comment: I have both `__main__.py` and `__init__.py` but always: `can't open file 'sfind': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @lepiloff cd to directory that contains `sfind` folder and run `python sfind`

Comment: Ricky Kim, yes. I added file structure to my question

Comment: @lepiloff directory that contains `sfind` not `sfind.py`. try `python \\absolute\path\to\sfind`

Comment: Same result, if I run `python \\absolute\path\to\sfind\sfinde.py` it works, but if run `python \\absolute\path\to\sfind\sfind`   -error occured

Comment: @lepiloff it should be `python \\absolute\path\to\sfind` not `python \\absolute\path\to\sfind\sfind`